# What Amazon AWS AMI for web.py, mysql

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, web.py, amazon-ami

I am working a web.py app for realtime ad tracking and performance advertising and I am trying to deploy it on Amazon AWS.  I know nothing about linux or servers or anything and typically just do application development.

Does anyone have a recommended community AMI for AWS for python 2.6, mysql, and web.py?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well in this case I would advise you with the default Ubuntu Server Long Term Support packate which is currently 10.04.

Then ubuntuforums is a great point for finding help and most howto guides etc are based on debian or ubuntu and ubuntu has the biggest resource archives.

So you can basically install anything that needs complicated compilation very easily using the packag management tools. Even commercial software.